# Call self variables from within __new__ in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class PrepareData:
    def __init__(self, model, DATA_PATH, num_clusters):
        self.model = model
        self.data_path = DATA_PATH
        self.num_clusters = num_clusters

    def __new__(cls, model, DATA_PATH, , num_clusters):
        embeddings = self.get_matrix(MODEL_PATH = model, DATA_PATH = DATA_PATH)
        return embeddings
        
    def get_matrix(args):
       ...
```

I stumbled upon `__new__` in Python which allowed me to return a value directly along with the object creation without having to call every function within separately, which `__init__` cannot do for me.

I am now confused about how to call other self variables/functions within my class from my `__new__` method. I want to access the `get_matrix` function but it doesn't recognize `self`. I think there is an issue with positional arguments being assigned correctly. I don't quite understand how the `cls` part works either.

Comment: `__new__` is about how to create an instance, `__int__` is about to initialize it

Comment: It's not really clear what this is supposed to be doing, but it seems pretty likely that what you actually want here is a *function*.

Comment: Just to clarify, your title should have `__new__`, not `__next__` right?

Comment: "which allowed me to return a value directly along with the object creation without having to call every function within separately, which `__init__` cannot do for me." this doesn't make sense to me, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` it's called  first and it's responsible for instance creation (returns an instance) `cls` represents the class that is needed to be instantiated .

`__init__` it's only responsible for initialising the instance after creation (doesn't return anything)

Usually you shouldn't need to override `__new__` unless you're subclassing an immutable type like `str`, `int`, `tuple`.

Regarding the arguments for `__init__` and `__new__` the convention is as follows:

If the method is an **instance** method then the word `self` has to be used otherwise if the method is a **class** method then the `cls` must be used

Comment: `self` and `cls`  are neither reserved words nor keywords. And neither *must* be used in *any* case. `self` and `cls` are *merely conventions* for naming the first parameter to a method, depending on if that method gets an instance (for instance methods) for the class, for classmethods (`__new__` is the only default classmethod). You *can* use any name you want, `foo`, `this`, `banana`... any valid identifier

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your answer has no downvotes. And the use of the terms *keyword* and *reserved word* imply the opposite, at the very least, they are used incorrectly

Comment: You're right my bad, I've updated accordingly. I know that it's just a convention but in all fairness I never seen other words being used in a more or less professional environment.